# ContentPublication limit exceeded

Tags: apex, limits, content, contentversion, governorlimits

Is there a limit on the content publication ?

Is this the same as content version? The docs say "The maximum number of versions that can be published in a 24-hour period is 5,000. "

Does this include new/updating existing contents or only the modifications ?

Can someone throw some light on why this issue could happen ?

Comment: I just experienced that this error can even get thrown when creating content in sandbox using test methods

Comment: I experience the same issue , which my total attachment is only 4000 plus .I read the max is 200000 k, I have no idea why it hit the limit.

Comment: Just want to add, because we know total attachment is only 40000 plus we called Salesforce support and it turned up they set it 25k as default while we are using Enterprise so they set it to 200k.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at [the limit doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_file_size_limits.htm), the limit applies to any Content Documents and Versions, so that would include new docs, updates, everything. It also says that the limit is 'adjustable', so try calling Salesforce and asking for it to be increased.

Comment: Hi @Metadaddy Thanks for heads up, seems the link no longer available.

Comment: Well, it is over five years old! Google can probably help you find the current link.

Comment: Can you update the "the limit doc" link as it is broken? Perhaps to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_file_size_limits.htm?

Comment: Is there any way to check this limit?

Answer (score 4):

Anybody who wants to know more about the contentpublication. Exact words from SFDC.
"It’s a rolling limit.  Imagine you insert 1,000 file at 12:00 one day, and do nothing else for 24 hours.  You’ve consumed 1,000 of your 10,000 limit.  That level of consumption will remain until 12:01 the next day, at which point the limit drops back down to 0.  Now imagine you insert 1,000 files at 12:00 one day, and another 1,000 at 18:00 later that day.  You’ve now consumed 2,000 of your 10,000 limit.  At 12:01 the next day, your limit will drop down to 1,000 / 10,000, and after 18:01 it will reduce back down to zero.   In short, we continuously look back at the number consumed in the last 24th hour, reduce it from the limit, and then add in the number made within the most recent minute."