# Rolling Limit applies for Test classes?

Tags: apex, unit-test, governorlimits, failing-tests

I am using a test class and getting the error:

> System.UnexpectedException: ContentPublication Limit exceeded.

This is a rolling 24 hour limit.

Below is the code:

```
@IsTest 
private class ContentVersionTest { 
    static testmethod void testContentVersionLimits() { 
        Test.startTest(); 

        Integer count = 0; 

        SObjectBuilder builder = new SObjectBuilder(ContentVersion.SObjectType) 
            .put(ContentVersion.Title, 'Random') 
            .put(ContentVersion.PathOnClient, 'XYZ path') 
            .put(ContentVersion.VersionData, Blob.valueOf('Sampledata')) 
            .count(100);

        while(count < 500) { 
            builder.create(); 
        } 

        Test.stopTest(); 
    } 
}
```

I cannot re-run the test for another 24 hours once the limit hits. Why does this rolling limit affect my test class?

Comment: Possible answer here in http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/contentpublication-limit-exceeded

Comment: Better way to test limits is to have prod code test against a property that defaults to Limits.xxxx but can be overridden by testmethod injection to a much smaller value (e.g. 2).

Comment: This sounds like a bug. You may want to contact support.

Comment: `SObjectFactory` in the wild! Woot woot! Note that you can just `count(500)` and `create` once.

Comment: Have you @AdrianLarson fixed this issue? I got the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this issue happens whenever your test attempts multiple `insert` operations on the `ContentVersion` object. If you just consolidate into one `create` call, the test should pass:

```
static testmethod void testBulk()
{
    SObjectBuilder builder = new SObjectBuilder(ContentVersion.sObjectType)
        //...
        .count(500);

    Test.startTest();
        builder.create();
    Test.stopTest();

    // ADD ASSERTIONS
}

static testmethod void testMutipleInsert()
{
    SObjectBuilder builder = new SObjectBuilder(ContentVersion.sObjectType)
        //...
        .count(1);
    // the default count is 1, so you never need to actually call count(1)
    // in this example it is just to illustrate

    Test.startTest();
        builder.create();
        builder.create(); // will fail here
    Test.stopTest();

    // ADD ASSERTIONS
}
```

Comment: I wish to know why I cannot run this test after the limit is hit for 24 hrs. Its test class so limit should not apply for 24 hrs as per my understanding. Please confirm.

Comment: I'm saying it has **NOTHING TO DO WITH** the 24 hour limit. I reproduced this issue in an org that has not ever touched the limit, let alone within the last 24 hours.