# Help with "System.UnexpectedException: Note can't be saved" in batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

I am trying to create a batch apex job that will find all tasks within a date range (for testing I have it set to one date), create a note (ContentNote) and link it to the whatid or whoid from the task (ContentDocumentLink) and then delete the task. I cannot get it to insert the note. I have been reading a lot of salesforce documentation and forums, but I have not found an answer. Do I have to create a content version?

Below is my code, any help would be appreciated. The error happens on line 32 - 
    Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(newObjects, false);

```
global class archiveTasksBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable{

public final string query;
date mydate = date.today().addDays(-367);

public archiveTasksBatch() {
    query = 'Select WhoId, WhatId, Subject, Status, OwnerId, Id, Description, CreatedDate, ActivityDate From Task where ActivityDate = :mydate';
}
public void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
    Database.executeBatch(this, 100);
}
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope){
    list<ContentNote > newObjects = new list<ContentNote >();
    list<ContentDocumentLink  > newCDL = new list<ContentDocumentLink  >();

    for(Sobject s : scope){
        Task obj = (Task) s;
        String myString = obj.Description + obj.ActivityDate;
        Blob myBlob = Blob.valueof(myString.escapeHtml4());
        newObjects.add(new ContentNote (
        Title = obj.Subject,
        Content = myBlob
        ));
        system.debug('*********************************' +newObjects.size());
        system.debug('*********************************' +scope.size());

        if(!newObjects.isEmpty()){
            Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(newObjects, false);
            for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
                if(sr.isSuccess() && obj.WhatId != null) {
                    ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
                    cdl.ContentDocumentId = sr.getId();
                    cdl.LinkedEntityId = obj.WhatId;
                    cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
                    cdl.ShareType = 'V';
                    newCDL.add(cdl);
                if(sr.isSuccess()&& obj.WhoId != null) {
                    ContentDocumentLink cdl2 = new ContentDocumentLink();
                    cdl2.ContentDocumentId = sr.getId();
                    cdl2.LinkedEntityId = obj.WhoId;
                    cdl2.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
                    cdl2.ShareType = 'V';
                    newCDL.add(cdl2);  
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    try{
        insert newCDL;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        system.debug(e.getMessage());
    }

    delete scope;
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    system.debug('JOB IS FINISHED');
}
```

}

UPDATE - 
I found that when I had accidentally set LinkedEntityId to the task id (first time I ran it) it worked. It created the note and deleted the tasks. However, since I linked it to the task none of the notes are linked to a record. So, at one point it "worked". 
Also, now when I try to create a note using the button on the contact I get the error "ContentPublication Limit exceeded." which, I am assuming, is why I can no longer create the note from the batch - hence the error there. 
I am clueless as to what to do next, found some more documentation to read through - in the meantime, if you have any help I would love to hear it.

Comment: So is the problem now addressing the "ContentPublication Limit exceeded" exception? If so, it sounds like that limit is adjustable - [ContentPublication limit exceeded](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1750/102)

Comment: The issue was resolved once the limit reset. I do have another issue now, should I create a new thread?

Comment: Here is the new question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174802/multiple-contentdocumentlink-records-created-not-sure-what-to-do-to-fix-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a post in [System.UnexpectedException: Note can't be saved](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000fy6QIAQ) that suggests `String.escapeHTML4()` is not sufficient to set the ContentNote.Content field. They've even gone as far as creating a github project to correct for it. - [DMRNoteAttachmentImporter](https://github.com/davidmreed/DMRNoteAttachmentImporter)

> The following steps are required to prepare note content for insertion into Salesforce:
>
> 1. Replace all basic HTML characters (<>"'&) with their corresponding entities (& and friends).
> 2. Replace all line breaks with `<br>` (taking care with Windows CRLF/Linux LF/Mac CR)
> 3. Replace ' with `&#39;`.
> 4. Do *not* replace Unicode characters with entities. Other entities, including `&apos;`, result in an exception. Unicode should be left as the bare characters.
> 5. Ensure that the source content is well-formed Unicode/UTF-8 and does not contain non-printable characters.
> 6. The title must not be null, zero-length, or consist only of whitespace. The title need not be escaped.
>
> All but (5) are handled by this package. You are responsible for ensuring that supplied text is well-formed.

At the very least, check the characters you are trying to insert into the Content. There are likely to be encoding issues.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!I read through that and tried just setting the content to just "test". I was still getting the error.

I did just update my question. I may have a different issue than I originally thought.