# ContentNote - INVALID_INPUT which characters are invalid

Tags: rest-api, contentnote

I am trying to use REST API to update the content of `ContentNote` object.

I am submitting base64 encoded content, e.g. this:
`PHA+cmFiYml0PC9wPjxwPjxicj48L3A+PHA+PG9sPjxsaT48Yj5UZXN0PC9iPjxicj48L2xpPjxsaT48Yj5XPC9iPjwvbGk+PC9vbD48L3A+`

Which is 
`<p>rabbit</p><p><br></p><p><ol><li><b>Test</b><br></li><li><b>W</b></li></ol></p>`

The response is

> [{"message":"Note can't be saved because it contains HTML tags or unescaped characters that are not allowed in a Note.","errorCode":"INVALID_INPUT","fields":[]}]

However, i can't see which characters are invalid HTML here?

This piece of documentation vaguely alludes to the fact that lists may not be supported:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232870&type=1

Is there a definitive list of what is allowed and what is NOT allowed in a SNOTE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Salesforce support, with API v45 we can now use ContentNote with HTML without messing about with unsupported chars.

The only official documentation the support was able to point me to was:

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_notes.htm

With this version of API i wasn't so far been able to break this (although we've parked the feature for now and i've not tried too hard).

Answer (score 0):

The most comprehensive documentation I'm aware of is the Knowledge article you linked and [this one](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000230867&language=en_US&type=1), which is silent on HTML and addresses only plaintext Notes.

However, I think the first document shows why this Note is not being accepted:

> - The following tags or elements in bold are accepted in the .txt file in order to format the note's text:

```
<i>Italic text</i>
<strong>Bold text</strong>
<u>Underlined text</u>
```

You have `<b>` where it's expecting `<strong>`.

> It's not currently possible to insert Notes via the Data Loader with advanced formatting such as unordered (bullets) and ordered (numbered) lists or indentations using either a .html or .txt file.

Your body includes ordered lists, which I read this to say one cannot do via the API (since that's what Data Loader is using).

I tried stripping those tags out, yielding

```
<p>rabbit</p><p><br></p><p><strong>Test</strong><br><strong>W</strong></p>
```

and did

```
PATCH /services/data/v45.0/sobjects/ContentNote/<note id>
{
    "Content": "PHA+cmFiYml0PC9wPjxwPjxicj48L3A+PHA+PHN0cm9uZz5UZXN0PC9zdHJvbmc+PGJyPjxzdHJvbmc+Vzwvc3Ryb25nPjwvcD4="
}
```

and it worked exactly as expected.

[image]

Comment: this is great for this one example. How cant guarantee users won’t input something else tomorrow? :) i am looking for a comprehensive solution

Comment: @zaitsman I am not sure there is a comprehensive solution; `ContentNote` validation is [marked by its strange behavior](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256335/note-cant-be-saved-error-on-contentnote-insert/256359#256359) in general. In continuing to experiment, however, I've actually gotten your original example to succeed, for reasons I don't know yet.

Comment: FYI @DavidReed apparently the changes come in with API v45, and those allow a lot more HTML in ContentNote than before.

Comment: @zaitsman Thanks for tracking that down!